# How to remove parentheses from string

Tags: python, regex

This:

```
document = re.sub(r"(\)", " ", document)
```

or this:

```
document = re.sub(r"()", " ", document)
```

do not work for me.

So how can I simply remove the parentheses from a text.

For example this:

```
document = "(Hello World)"
```

to become this:

```
document = "Hello World"
```

Comment: `document.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')`

Comment: If you want to replace just all `)` or `(` you have to use a character class `[()]` like `document = re.sub(r"[()]", " ", document)`

Comment: `re.sub(r"[()]", " ", document)`

Comment: Your input looks very specific. Why can't you  just do `document.strip("()")`? Or use @OlvinRoght solution

Comment: Why are you using regex when 1) it's absolutely unnecessary and 2) you have no idea how it works? Looking at the code you posted and the questions you asked in comments, it's clear that you don't know the first thing about regex. Have you read a tutorial yet?

Answer (score 12):

```
document.replace('(','').replace(')','')
```

Use `replace` method.

Comment: upvote because it does not require the regex module

Answer (score 8):

If you simply want to remove all parentheses in the string, use this:

```
document = '(Hello World)))))(((('
document = re.sub(r'[()]', '', document)
# square brackets, [], will capture anything inside them, in this case, any '(' or ')'

print(document)
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try :

```
>>> import re
>>> document = "(Hello World)"
>>> print(re.sub('[()]', '', document))
Hello World
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
import re

document = "(Hello World)"
print(re.sub(r"\((.*?)\)", r"\1", document))
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good (upvote) I will need please an explanation of how what you write achieve this. For example, what is the point of the questionmark etc.

Comment: Also does this work for all instances of parentheses? For example if by accident there is only only one left parentheses e.g. `(Hello World`.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit. if you have single parentheses. Óscar López solution should work.

Comment: Ok, it is good in general to explain at which instances something that you write works.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit..https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html has all the info. EX: `?` --> matches either once or zero times

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
re.sub(r"\(|\)", "", document)
```

Comment: thanks but to start with what is the point of `|` in this expression?

Comment: Also what if I told that I want to remove all parentheses & brackets? (I can write a separate question for this perhaps)

Comment: We use `|` to say: match either this or this character. It's an OR. If you need to match several characters, it's simpler to use character classes, like this: `[({})]`